# How do I monitor resource consumption of a process starting up?

Tags: process, monitoring

I am trying to figure out how to monitor or figure out how much memory/cpu/time it takes to start a specific process in linux. Many tools I have looked into such as pipstat, perf and atop all require an existing pid.

The challenge for me is that I want to figure out the resource consumption **at the time the process is booting up**. For example, running `systemctl start <process_name>` From my understanding a pid has not been assigned till it is already running.

I tried to use atop but couldn't get a very good granularity from that in the logs.

The closest thing I have so far is using systemmd-bootchart which has gotten me an idea of how long it takes to start up some processes but it does not tell me resource consumption and I have to restart the system every time.

**Any ideas on how I can get the resource consumption/total boot time of a process starting up?**

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas on how I can get the resource consumption/total boot time of
>   a process at startup?

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze blame
```

will give you a list of unit startup times from the boot process.

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for more details on the process/application start up and not the system boot up. At time T, I initiate to start a process, lets say 'systemctl start <process>', which finishes to boot at T+1, how do i figure out total mem,cpu, and time it took between T and T+1. i was able to use 'perf stat <command>' to get the time but it doesn't show me mem usage